# Example Hook form validate, get all node information after save news field

Tags: forms, entities

In a custom module, I do some operations on several content node (add field_collections and save)
After that, I need to get all field_collections of my content nodes.
But when I get, I have the old field_collections and not the new field_collections I just save.

Exemple :

```
//I have this node in my submit hook
node0
    ->field0
    ->filed1

//I save a new field (via entity_metadata_wrapper and save() ), and I get this node after
//I Have
node0
    ->field0
    ->filed1    

//But I would like have 
node0
    ->field0
    ->filed1    
    ->field2 //the new field I just save
```

Are there a Hook I can use after a validate form ? But I would like keep the information about who nodes has been save...for get only them
Or an other way I don't know ?

I don't think I can clear the cache because my operations "save" and after "get" are in a heavy foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab your information before the node is saved you can use [`hook_node_presave`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), then if you want to gather information after its successfully saved simply use [`hook_node_update`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7).

Also if you are saving it via the `entity_metadata_wrapper` you should still have access to the data after its saved.

```
$entity_wrapper->field_name->value(); //Should have field0, field1

//Add your value here

$entity_wrapper->save();

$entity_wrapper->field_name->value(); // Should have field0, field1, field2
```